# Prevent a form from sending if one of its input doesn't have a certain value

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Right now when I submit the contact form with an input value other than 4, a successful message "Thanks, I'll get back to you soon!" returns and then the form is cleared. What should I change so that if I do enter an input value other than 4, the form is prevented from sending and user is alerted that the form failed?

I'm using this plugin for my contact form: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

```
// Contact form 
(function(){

    var contactForm = $('form#contact'),
        inputCheck = $('input.check'),
        contactCheck = $('div#contact-check');

    // Check if answered math question correctly
    inputCheck.keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 4){
            contactCheck.fadeOut();
        } else {
            contactCheck.fadeIn();
        }
    });

    // Validate input from contact form
    $('form#contact').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            clearForm: true,
            success: function(){
                // if it's good, do this
                contactCheck.fadeOut();
                alert("Thanks, I'll get back to you soon!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
        invalidHandler: function(form) {
            // if it's bad, do this
            alert('Oops, something went wrong.');
        }
    });   


})();
```

Comment: Check the value at the top of your submit handler, and react accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom validation rule like

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("value", function (value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || params == value;
}, "Please specify the correct value");
```

then add a rule for the required element

```
// Validate input from contact form
$('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
        check: {
            required: true,
            value: 4
        }
    },
    messages: {
        check: {
            value: 'The value must be 4'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            clearForm: true,
            success: function () {
                // if it's good, do this
                contactCheck.fadeOut();
                alert("Thanks, I'll get back to you soon!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form) {
        // if it's bad, do this
        alert('Oops, something went wrong.');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2WVjk/)

Comment: What if I don't want the message to appear but instead just want the form to stop from being sent?